# Beautifulsoup class find is returning None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.takealot.com/huawei-p30-lite-128gb-dual-sim-midnight-black/PLID54510701"

page = requests.get(URL).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(class_="cell auto")

print(title)
```

Comment: the content is retrieve by javascript , probably you will need to use selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL contains no data, the page loads data via Javascript dynamically. However, if you inspect in Firefox/Chromefox Network inspector, where the page is making requests, you can get the data from specified URLs. For example:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.takealot.com/huawei-p30-lite-128gb-dual-sim-midnight-black/PLID54510701"
json_url = 'https://api.takealot.com/rest/v-1-9-0/product-details/{}?platform=desktop'

data = requests.get(json_url.format(URL.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])).json()

# print( json.dumps(data, indent=4) )  # <-- uncomment this to print all data

soup = BeautifulSoup( data['description']['html'], 'html.parser' )

print(soup.get_text(separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
Huawei P30 lite 4GB+128GB Dual SIM - Midnight Black


Quick Spec:
Display - 6.15" | 2312 x 1080 (FHD) Resolution
Memory - 4GB RAM | 128GB ROM
Camera - Rear Camera: 24 MP + 8 MP + 2 MP | Front Camera: 32 MP
SIM - Dual SIM | Nano-SIM 
Battery - 3340 mAh
Features:
Beauty in Every Shot
- Every face is different and unique. HUAWEI’s AI-driven Selfie technology beautifies your self-portraits based on your unique face shape and type. The technology maps the contours of your features and creates a custom algorithm to ensure you always show your best side.
Wider View. Wider Possibilities
- Broaden your perspective with the HUAWEI P30 lite's 120° Ultra-Wide Angle lens and capture expansive landscapes in stunning shots that leave nothing out of sight. Shoot without limits.
Stunning Display
- See, do and create more with the all-new HUAWEI P30 lite Dewdrop Display. Big, bold and beautiful, the 6.15" FHD display with a delicate Dewdrop notch is a gorgeous canvas for you to live your life in brilliant colour. Plus, the screen has TÜV Rheinland Eye Comfort Certification and is designed to be easier on the eyes for a more comfortable viewing experience.
Sleek Design
- Stylish and streamlined; the HUAWEI P30 lite fits comfortably in the palm of your hand. The slim 3D curved glass design is crafted for easy grip and one-handed use. It’s available in three colours, including an eye-catching iridescent gradient colour finish.

...and so on.
```

Comment: its cool solution but it needs a lot of effort to extract all required api links

Comment: @a_m_dev It depends what information OP needs. This link I found in Network tab quickly - it was one with biggest Transferred size.

Comment: Could you give a break down of the code, I am new to python and battling to understand

Comment: @BrandonCalitz There aren't much code. The main point of the script is to get last part of the URL `"https://www.takealot.com/huawei-p30-lite-128gb-dual-sim-midnight-black/PLID54510701"`  (PLID54510701) and use this last part to get data from URL `https://api.takealot.com/rest/v-1-9-0/product-details/PLID54510701?platform=desktop`. The data is in JSON format - when you uncomment the print statement, you will see what else is inside (not only description).

Comment: if I put "purchase_price" in the place of description it gives me a keyerror

Comment: @BrandonCalitz The `data` variable is dictionary with some fixed structure, so you may not put keys in it at random places. Uncomment the `print` statement to see, how the dictionary is structured and then you will know how to obtain your information from it.

Comment: @AndrejKesely my line of code is:     soup = BeautifulSoup(data['event_data']['documents']['product']['purchase_price'], 'html.parser' )     and recieving:   TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() trying to get the purchase_price in event_data

Comment: @BrandonCalitz `data['event_data']['documents']['product']['purchase_price']` is of type `float`. Don't put it inside the BeautifulSoup. `print( data['event_data']['documents']['product']['purchase_price'] )` should be enough :)